# Amazon S3 ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I am using IAM Users credentials who has following policy attached to it

AmazonS3FullAccess

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

But gets `Access Denied`

```
# aws s3 ls
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListBuckets operation: Access Denied
```

I do see credentials I set using `aws configure` are in `~/.aws/credentials` also `aws sts get-caller-identity` correct user.

I don't understand what I am missing here.

Comment: Have you added the Access key and secret in your environment? You can check it on `cat ~/.aws/credentials`

Comment: Seems like you have not used the access and secret key. Can you post the code that shows how you are specifying your creds.

Comment: I suspect that either you are not using the credentials that you think you are (use STS GetCallerIdentity or `aws sts get-caller-identity` to confirm) or those credentials do not have the permissions you think they do (review the policies).

Comment: I figure-out this was because of MFA policy attached to this user. After removing this policy it worked.

Comment: @roy write that up as an answer. It will help someone in future.

Answer (score 1):

I figure-out this was because of MFA policy attached to this user. After removing this policy it worked.

Comment: I'm having the same issue but in my case I can't remove the MultiFactorAuthPresent :-(